# Generating Maths quiz by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am tasked to edit an external javascript file for a basic Maths quiz for my schoolwork (not allowed to touch the html and the css). I'm very new to programming, and have attempted the question, but it doesn't work. I need some help here, so thanks in advance.

In this maths quiz, when the user clicks on the "Check" button, an alert box will appear, telling if the user has entered the answer correctly or wrongly, or a 'you have not entered anything'. After the user dismissed the alert box, the maths operands will change to a new random number from 1 to 10, which in turn generates a new question. Only the addition maths operator is used in this.

I've tried the 'callback' function to prompt the generation of the random numbers after clicking on the alert box button, as well as the 'if else' to determine which messages to appear on the alert box. I have no idea where are the errors or if I am in the right track in the first place 
Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/15t4g4sk/2/

Here's my jquery

```
var num1=document.getElementById("number1").value;
var num2=document.getElementById("number2").value;
var total = num1 + num2;
//feedback for click
```

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){

```
//if user didn't enter any field
if ($(":text") === '') {
    //callback to generate 2 random numbers
        $("button").click(function(){

    //generate a random number range 1 to 9 for number 1 after clicking alert box using callback function
        document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    //generate a random number range 1 to 9 for number 2 after clicking alert box using callback function
        document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    //alert box feedback
    alert("You have not key in any answer");


    //if user enter a correct answer
    } else if (answer == total) {
    //callback to generate 2 random numbers
        $("button").click(function(){

    //generate a random number range 1 to 9 for number 1 after clicking alert box using callback function
        document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    //generate a random number range 1 to 9 for number 2 after clicking alert box using callback function
        document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    //alert box feedback before generating random numbers
        alert("You have key in the wrong answer");
        }); 

    //if user enter a wrong answer
    } else {

    //callback to generate 2 random numbers
        $("button").click(function(){

    //generate a random number range 1 to 10 for number 1 after clicking alert box using callback function
        document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

    //generate a random number range 1 to 10 for number 2 after clicking alert box using callback function
        document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

    //alert box feedback before generating random numbers
        alert("You have key in the wrong answer");
                                    }); 
});
}});
```

Comment: what part of `enter code here` didn't you understand? Questions should be self contained and not rely on external site for us to see your code

Comment: sorry about that. i just put up my jquery codes.

Comment: Include the link to fiddle though, is helpful for those that want to help debug after reviewing your code

Comment: So tell us what's working and what isn't. I just checked the fiddle and the code you now posted is different.

Comment: Apology once again. I just updated my post with the fiddle. I was able to prompt for an alert box after clicking on the "Check" button only, but after I added the rest (Else If, generation of the random numbers, callback etc) it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete substitute for your javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
            //alert box feedback before generating random numbers
        var num1=parseInt($("#number1").text());
        var num2=parseInt($("#number2").text());
        var total = num1 + num2;
        var answer = parseInt($("input[type='text']").val());

        if ($("input[type='text']").val() === '') {
            alert("You have not key in any answer");
        } else if (answer === total) {
            alert("You have key in the right answer");
        } else {
            alert("You have key in the wrong answer");
        }

        //generate a random number range 1 to 9 for number 1 after clicking alert box using callback function
        $("#number1").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

        //generate a random number range 1 to 9 for number 2 after clicking alert box using callback function
        $("#number2").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    });
});
```

Live Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/15t4g4sk/13/);

Notes:

- You only need a single callback / event handler. The whole point in event programming is that you define a handler only once while  it will be called many times - ie.  each time a triggering event of the proper type occurs. This would be the type for which you registered the event handler in the first place.
- if you are using jquery, use it consistently - when querying element data from the html, use only the jquery selectors ( `$("<your selector"`)) or only dom functions ( eg. `queryElementById("<id>">` ). An exception to the rule is performance optimization. That should not be an issue for your average interface.
- Watch out for intricacies of type conversions. All data read from the dom are strings (simplifying a bit here). The checks you perform are on numbers. Thus you have to convert between types (which is good practice anyway). Thanks to overloading (notably of the operator `+`), the actual types of content cannot be deduced by the js runtime engine.

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest solution. so u can easily understand..

> ```
> var num1=document.getElementById("number1").value;
> var num2=document.getElementById("number2").value;    var total = num1 + num2;    //feedback for click
>  $(document).ready(function(){
> $("input[type=button]").on("click", function(){
>     var num1 = $("#number1").html().trim();
>     var num2 = $("#number2").html().trim();
>     var sum = parseFloat(num1)+parseFloat(num2);
>     var inputsum = $("#sum").val();
>     if(sum  == inputsum)
>     {
>         alert("currect answer");
>         $("#number1").html(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)); 
>         $("#number2").html(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)); 
>     }
>     else{
>         alert("wrong answer");
>     }
> }); });
> ```